# Google consent screen shows error 403 access_denied

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I have a verified google app, while testing different scenarios I faced the following ...

**I have the backend running on localhost while testing this ..**

- for the very first time, when I try to login, I get the below consent
  screen.
- I don't select any permissions and just click continue.
- in the backend I can see am receiving a code from which I generate
  the tokens and the flow works as expected

[image]

**I then sign out and try to sign in again ...**

I now receive this consent screen, when I click continue, I receive a confirmation message (didn't happen in the first time)

[image]
[image]

when I choose `continue` in the popup, I can see am longer receiving a code and instead am receiving `error=access_denied`

please note that the app in production and verified

in the backend, am using this endpoint to generate signin URL

```
app.get("/endpoint/login", (req, res) => {
  const scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  ];
  const authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: scopes,
    include_granted_scopes: true,
  });
  // console.log(authUrl);
  res.status(200).json({ authUrl });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time has some automatic scopes added because you are using sign-in.

[image]

The second time those are gone. so as the error states

[image]

Comment: I expected to a get a token with the allowed scopes, but in that case, how do I get a new token ?

Comment: As its signin your probably going to have to request all scopes again.

Comment: I've updated  the question with sign-in url generation logic,  can you please elaborate how to request all scopes again ?

note : I tried to set `include_granted_scopes` to `false` and am getting same resuls